# Store form data to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I have a webpage where I have a textbox, preferably for storing email addresses.

I need to create an email intake database with a simple database built to store users' emails “signing up”.

One of the ways I think this is using an Excel document on Google Drive, the other being a standalone DB.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the Forms functionality that is already provided by Google: http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=87809

This help article shows you how to set up a form, and the form responses go to a Google Spreadsheet with all of the data. You could create a simple form that asks users to enter an email address and hit "Submit"

The easiest way to create a form is:

- Create a Google Spreadsheet
- Click *Form* > *Create Form*
- Add your question(s) and edit your question types

Once the form is created:

- Click *Form* > *Embed Form in a Webpage*

You can then use the `<iframe>` to embed the form onto your site.

Comment: **Note for new visitors**: Not all the questions should be answered. See [answer]. The site scope changed when [softwarerecs.se] was launched, making questions asking for recommendations off-topic. Ref [Meta post](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2595/88163).

Answer (score 0):

How are you validating that the email addresses which are entered into your form do actually belong to people who want to sign up.

For example, I could go to your form and enter barack.obama@whitehouse.govt   (or whatever) - that doesn't mean that the lucky soul who gets emails sent to that address wants to sign up.

One option that would provide a validation-step is to use a Feedburner feed (of something that never gets anything new sent to it).   Put the feedburner email sign-up into your website, and then use Feedburner to get an excel-format list of subscribers when you need it.

Comment: **Note for new visitors**: Not all the questions should be answered. See [answer]. The site scope changed when [softwarerecs.se] was launched, making questions asking for recommendations off-topic. Ref [Meta post](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2595/88163).